# Difference between in C and C++ types (typedef)

Tags: c++, c, types, typedef

I'm trying to understand the difference between C and C++, by redesigning the API of a project that I've done during my semester from DB class (creating own database system) written in C language. Now I'm trying redesign the API of project that it can be used in applications written in C++ language also.

I have got confused with `typedef struct`, `enum`, `float` etc.

My code in C for the header file looks like:

```
typedef enum { FALSE = 0, TRUE } bool_t;
typedef float  real;
...
typedef  struct _hf_record_identification {
    int pagenum;
    int recnum;
} RECID;
```

I've reached the conclusion, after reading a few references about it, that it can be represented in C++ like:

```
enum bool_t {FALSE = 0, TRUE };
float real;
...
struct _hf_record_identification RECID {
    int pagenum;
    int recnum;
} ;
```

My question is: what is the main difference between `typedef` in C and `typedef` in
C++? It's not inconvenient to use `typedef` in C++ for me. I'm confusing it with C. Have I done it correctly for `typedef float real` case?

Comment: but why? C++ already has ***typedef struct, enum, float***

Comment: With `typedef` you create an *alias* for another type.

Comment: "Not inconvenient to use `typedef`"? It's not clear what it is you're asking exactly. Also, note that, with few exceptions, C code is also valid C++ code (albeit not the best thing to use in C++ necessarily), so you C code snippet should compile and work.

Comment: `typedef float  real;` don't. Code is about communication, and you aren't communicating well here. All C and C++ programmers know what a float is, but they have no idea what you mean exactly by a real. Sure, they can look it up, but your just made it harder to communicate your intent to them. This typedef is not an abstraction, it's syntactic sugar.

Comment: In c you need to `typedef` structs to avoid writing `struct RECID` everytime. In c++ you can use `RECID` without `struct` automatically.

Comment: If you want to use from C++ something written in C, then check the concept of `extern C {}`. If you want to write a C->C++ wrapper, then share your mutual experiences with Bjarne Stroustrup. He quite successfully did something similar, but it was so much work that many people have noticed it.

Comment: Please clarify your question.

Comment: Also, `typedef float real;` and `float real;` are two different thing.

Comment: @StoryTeller I apologise if i wasn't enough clear, of course, i know what is float. by `real` i mean real type.

Comment: @Nusha_Gadim - You didn't catch my drift. I wasn't critiquing your post or understanding of C++ and C. I was telling you that this typedef is syntactic sugar only, and in fact makes your code worse to read.

Comment: Note that the name `_hf_record_identification` is treading on thin ice.  Such names are reserved for the implementation — though I grant you that the implementation is unlikely to use that particular name.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This line:

```
typedef float real;
```

is really just a `typedef`, it defines `real` as an alias for the type `float`. So if you write

```
float real;
```

it is *not* the same, neither in C nor in C++. It's just a declaration of a variable `real` with type `float`.

---

Things get a bit more complicated with `struct` and `enum`, because they have so-called *tags* to identify them:

```
struct foo
{
    int x;
};
```

Here: `foo` is the struct's tag. In C++, you can refer to the struct by only writing the tag (as long as the tag name is unambiguous), while C requires you to always include the `struct` keyword:

```
struct foo a; // legal in both C and C++
foo b;        // legal only in C++
```

Of course, you can also create an alias type using `typedef`, taking the example above:

```
typedef struct foo foo;
```

Now, the second declaration is valid C as well, because `foo` is a type name.

The same rules apply in the same way to `enum`s.

Note that C++ does **not** "*automatically typedef*" a `struct` or `enum`. It only allows to refer to these types by using the tag name alone. So, an additional `typedef` is absolutely valid C++.

Therefore, if your code should work with both C and C++ (a requirement you typically only have for header files) just declare your `struct`s like this:

```
typedef struct foo foo;
struct foo
{
    // members
};
```

or condensed into a single declaration:

```
typedef struct foo
{
    // members
} foo;
```

---

Note there's an additional pitfall with C++. Consider the following code:

```
struct foo
{
    int x;
};

typedef struct foo *foo;
```

(Side note: `typedef`ing pointers is a bad habit, only used here for simple demonstration)

This code is valid C, but **not** valid C++. The reason is that C++ requires a `typedef` of the same name as a struct or enum tag to refer to exactly the same struct or enum type. In C, there's no such requirement.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, but i still have some question about, in the case of `RECID` case.  If I did understand you correctly, in second typedef example i can leave it as it is in c++ also?

Comment: @Nusha_Gadim the final example for `RECID` you show is wrong, it tries to add two struct tags (`_hf_record_identification` and `RECID`) to the same struct, this isn't possible (both languages). Just leave it at the first version ... a `typedef` of a struct doesn't *have* to use the same name as the struct tag, so the first code is again valid in both languages.

Answer (score 1):

This method is very much obsolete. To write C code that is C++ compatible, you would use the native bool type of both languages (which was introduced in C at the year 1999) and not some 1990s macros.

`#include <stdbool.h>` then use `bool`, `true` and `false`.

Even if C++ compatibility is not desired, using your own, home-brewed bool type is always bad practice in C.

Comment: This should have been a comment, as it does not really answer the question. Nevertheless, very good advice.

Comment: @cmaster The question is "My question is, why it's not inconvenient to use typedef in c++?" and the answer is, you shouldn't use typedef for booleans in either language.

Comment: Nope, the question is much broader. Note how the OP gives examples about `struct`, `enum` and `float`. The `bool` thing is just a tangent.

Comment: @polkovnikov.ph It does attempt to answer the question. If it doesn't, then it is because the question is unclear and I have misunderstood it. In which case the question should get closed.

Comment: @polkovnikov.ph I am well aware. As a reviewer, it is your task to determine if the answer attempts to answer the question or not. Delete votes are for answers that do not attempt to answer the question, not for answers that are merely poor.

Answer (score 0):

There is not much (more precisely: not any) use in re-creating the C interface identically just by replacing `typedef enum {} X` with `enum X {}` etc. as the C code is accepted well by C++, too – unless you are facing any of those view C-features incompatible to C++ (such as a VLA used in an inline function in the header). Otherwise, you are just duplicating code which will lead to maintainability issues without any further profit.

Sure, a C++ wrapper *can* be useful, but you'd create a C++ like interface for an existing C interface introducing object orientation and possibly polymorphism, such as demonstrated below:

```
// FILE wrapper in C++:
class File
{
    FILE* handle;
public:
    int read();
    int write();
    // or whatever you consider appropriate
};

// sockets:
class Socket
{
public:
    // some appropriate common interface
};
class SocketTCP : public Socket
{
    // appropriate specialization...
};
class SocketUDP : public Socket
{
    // appropriate specialization...
};
```

Quite likely, you might replace the C structs with such classes, which are wrapping around the C types then, the enums, though, you might leave as are - unless you want them to have a different scope (e. g. nest some of them inside the classes or a namespace).